# Refraction after leaving a transparent (glass) object

Tags: raytracing

I'm currently writing a fragment shader, which (besides other things) imitates the refraction effect on a glass sphere.

So, when a ray enters the sphere, the ray changes direction. So far so good. Now, when the refracted ray *leaves* the glass object, does it change direction again? I'm pretty sure it does, but I've been poking around the Internet and I've found different opinions (e.g. at the bottom of [this](http://www.physicstutorials.org/home/optics/refraction-of-light/the-laws-of-refraction) site it's clearly stated that there is no change in direction).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be worth asking this on [Physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/). Not entirely sure your question is on-topic here as it has more to do with the physics of the ray than any actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it changes... the angle from air to glass refraction is the same then from glass to air.

You can implement it very easily. First you have to render your scene in a cubemap which is centered inside the sphere.
the 2nd renderstep uses the normalvector and the camera position to point vector, with them you can use the function refract() to calculate the vector of the refraction.
You have to calculate where the ray goes out of the sphere and you also can use the refract funtion again. you only have to calculate the normalvector of the outputplace again.
the 3rd step is to use the texture() function of the cubemap and put the outputvector as coordinate inside the function.

Comment: So. When I first refract the ray (from air to glass) my refractive index quotient (the third parameter in the refract glsl function) is **1.0 / 1.5** and when the ray leaves the object (from glass to air) it is **1.5 / 1.0** ?

Comment: there you have to calculate the normalvector of the outputpoint, and you can also use the funtion refract. but it is not the same value then the inside refraction. it is only calculated the same way..